# zsh doesn't complete local dir name when trying to execute local executable

Tags: zsh

I have a local directory with executable in it (e.g. foo_dir/bin/bar).  I typed "foo", but foo_dir wasn't suggested.  What cames out is other program in $PATH (such as bootlogd).

How should I config my zshrc?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think adding "." to your $PATH variable will fix this issue. By default $PATH contains standard bin directory i.e /usr/bin, /bin, /usr/local/bin.

Comment: It works, but is there better way to do that?  I don't want to pollute my $PATH.

Comment: Adding `.` to `$PATH` is a bad idea for security reasons. Please don't do it.

Comment: then add your foo_dir/bin to $PATH... :)

Comment: hmm... maybe i need to write my own completer... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workable solution, by "setopt autocd", but the side effect is when executing some directory, you'll cd into it.